# Tensorflow freeze protobuf file checkpoint file doesn't exist

Tags: android, python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, tensorflow-lite

I'm working with retrain.python file from this demo.
I'm getting different types of files:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to freeze the graph.pb with the checkpoints files, to optimize the frozen file then to convert optimized file to tflite file in order to use it in android app.

I'm tried different ways to freeze the file but no luck,

> getting checkpoint file doesn't exist in Terminal

and

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x86 in position
>   1: invalid start byte

How to complete all steps and get the tflite file and how to combine the labels.txt file?

Note: 
Here is the command I used in Terminal:

```
python freeze_graph.py \ 
--input_graph=/home/automator/Desktop/retrain/code/graph/graph.pb \ 
--input_checkpoint=/home/automator/Desktop/retrain/code/tmp/model.ckpt \ 
--output_graph=/home/automator/Desktop/retrain/code/frozen.pb \ 
--output_node_names=output_node \
--input_saved_model_dir=/home/automator/Desktop/retrain/code/export/frozen.pb \ --output_node_names=outInput
```

The Error:
checkpoint '' doesn't exist!

**Tried:**

```
--input_checkpoint=/home/automator/Desktop/retrain/code/tmp/model.ckpt
--input_checkpoint=/home/automator/Desktop/retrain/code/tmp/model
--input_checkpoint=/home/automator/Desktop/retrain/code/tmp/modelmodel.ckpt
....
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice script to freeze a graph

```
import os
import argparse
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile


def load_graph_def(model_path, sess=None):
    if os.path.isfile(model_path):
        with gfile.FastGFile(model_path, 'rb') as f:
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
            tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
    else:
        sess = sess if sess is not None else tf.get_default_session()
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_path + '.meta')
        saver.restore(sess, model_path)


def freeze_from_checkpoint(checkpoint_file, output_layer_name):

    model_folder = os.path.basename(checkpoint_file)
    output_graph = os.path.join(model_folder, checkpoint_file + '.pb')

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        load_graph_def(checkpoint_file)

        graph = tf.get_default_graph()
        input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()

        print("Exporting graph...")
        output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
            sess,
            input_graph_def,
            output_layer_name.split(","))

        with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph, "wb") as f:
            f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('model_path')
    parser.add_argument('output_layer')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    freeze_from_checkpoint(checkpoint_file=args.model_path, output_layer_name=args.output_layer)
```

Save it as freeze_graph.py

Call it:
python freeze_graph.py /home/automator/Desktop/retrain/code/tmp/model.data-000000-of-00001 "output_node_name"

Comment: Meir,
Your nice code worked after changing 'model.data-000000-of-00001' to 'model'. First I got no such file then after changing it to model only worked fine but does it make sense that the meta file size is 2.2MB and the frozen file is 83Bytes only?
If so please let me know if you have fast way to convert the file to TFLite.
I tried this to convert=> convert_saved_model.convert(saved_model_dir....) but I don't want to convert the saved model.pb with variables But the frozen one.

Comment: I didn't get to convert any model to tflite yet, but maybe you can have a look here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.8/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms
bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:transform_graph
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph \
--in_graph=tensorflow_inception_graph.pb \
--out_graph=optimized_inception_graph.pb \
--inputs='Mul:0' \
--outputs='softmax:0' \

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have a `meta graph` saved, try using the `input_meta_graph` argument:

```
python freeze_graph.py \ 
--input_meta_graph=/home/automator/Desktop/retrain/code/tmp/model.meta \ 
--input_checkpoint=/home/automator/Desktop/retrain/code/tmp/model.ckpt \ 
--input_binary=true \
--output_graph=/home/automator/Desktop/retrain/code/frozen.pb \ 
--output_node_names=output_node
```

The issue is that you are passing the `--input_saved_model_dir` argument that [overwrites](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py#L227) the `input_meta_graph` argument but you don't seem to have a [SavedModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#build_and_load_a_savedmodel).

Comment: Tried adding all needed parameters but no luck, actually I prefer to find the best solution by python.

Comment: That's totally cool. Just curious though why the above command did not work out...what is the error you get when you run the above? Thanks.